# How to bookmark a shiny app whose UI is made up of functions?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

The UI of my shiny app is not in the fluid-page, but rather made up of functions that are defined in other R files. I am unaware as where to define the bookmarkButton() - in the main R file or individual R files.

```
    ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "black")

    header <- shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(
      tags$li(
        class = "dropdown",
        tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 100px;}"),
        tags$style(".main-header .logo {min-height: 60px;}")
    ),
sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
  tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {padding-top: 50px}"),
```

Comment: Each side-bar UI is an individual R file with some server logic functions.